# Why I can't use padding-left in a H1 tag

Tags: html, css

This is my web page project:
[image]

I want to centralize that "Login" text in the center, i know i can use `text-align:center;`. My question is: When I try to use `padding-left`  or `margin-left`, the text just doesn't move to the right.

This is my code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: url(test4.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 10, 0, 0.5);
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.password,
.password-input,
.username,
.username-input {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

.btn {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #35aa23;
  color: white;
}

.password,
.username {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.password-input,
.username-input {
  color: white;
  font: sans-serif;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #35aa23;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="username-div">
    <span class=" username ">Username</span>
  </div>

  <div class="username-input-div">
    <input type="text " class="username-input " name=" " id=" ">
  </div>

  <div class="password-div">
    <span class="password ">Password</span>
  </div>

  <div class="passoword-input-div">
    <input type="password" class="password-input ">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-div">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sig in">
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: could you share your code please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please create a [MRE] with the minimum relevant code required to recreate the problem you are having, so that we can see what is wrong and be able to help.

Comment: it is possible to use padding and margin. If it's not working there is something else in your code preventing it. Check @FluffyKitten comment.

Comment: I'd added the code into your question, but there is no problem with the code you have given us. You need to show us the problem you are having so we can help.

Comment: @Kratos the text is moving to the right by using `padding-left`. Maybe in your actual code, some selector is setting `padding` to 0. You can try using `!important`.

Comment: Because the container (.box) is set to display:absolute you need to tell h1 to display:block, otherwise text-align: center won't work.

Comment: @anatolhiman heading elements are block elements by default. Being used in a container with position:absolute doesn't affect that or the ability to use text-align on the h1.

Comment: @FluffyKitten You're right, I mixed it up. I meant that absolute positioned elements need an explicit width in order for child elements to be centered with text-align:center (this: https://jsfiddle.net/12t97can/). Weird that it doesn't work in OP's case, as he has set the width to 500px.

Comment: The OP obviously has something else going on in their code, either the css is being overridden or they made a mistake adding it. They will need to update their question to show us what they're doing, so we are *able* the help!

Answer (score 0):

When I add padding-left and margin-left to the style for h1, it seems to work fine:

```
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px; /* Added */
    margin-left: 50px; /* Added */
}
```

[Check it out here.](https://jsfiddle.net/kme1shdb/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code sample you added. I was able to alter the `h1` and move it using `padding-left` and `margin-left` without any problem.

Maybe you are overriding the code somewhere else. Or you are adding the new changes on top of the `h1` code therefore it is being overridden again to the original position.

### For testing sake only.

use `margin-left: 30px !important` if the text has moved it means you have a **CSS specificity issue**

"do not use it for the final product. It is Just for testing sake."

Just to confirm that you are overriding the value somewhere else without you noticing. If you found out the text moved from its place it means you have a CSS Specificity issue or you are overriding the value again somewhere else in your code.

And here is a great article [about CSS specificity](https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca#:%7E:text=CSS%20Specificity%20is%20the%20set,present%20on%20the%20element%27s%20style.)

And here is another great resource to help you out. [Precedence in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/)

Comment: Bad idea to center stuff using margin or padding. Use display: block + text-align: center or make the parent container display:flex and then center the items inside of that with justify-content: center.

Comment: I'm not saying he should do that. I'm trying to debug the issue here.

Comment: @AhmadDalao Answers on Stack Overflow are not meant for debugging, they should offer a solution to the problem in the question. If you would like to debug the problem with the OP, you should use comments or chat for that first, then when you have sufficient information then you can post you full and complete answer.

Comment: That will help him find his problem. Since he didn't give us enough code to work with. As I said the code he shared is working just fine. I'm trying to help him to figure out the answer. Maybe we are not on the same page. @FluffyKitten

Comment: That’s not how Stack Overflow works. This is a Q&A repository of questions and answers that are helpful to all users, so both questions and answers should be clear, specific and include all details (which this question doesn’t and is close to being closed).  Also FYI it is against site guidelines to answer questions that are unclear and don’t have enough information to help (like this one) see “Answer well-asked questions” in [ask]. Comments and chat can be used to help discuss the problem with the user and get the information needed, answers are not the place to do this.

Comment: You are annoyed that all I have to say. IF you have an answer post it and help him out.

Comment: I’m just pointing out the guidelines for using this site. Not meeting guidelines can get questions and answers downvoted or even removed. Please review the help center and in particular “Answer well-asked questions” in [answer] *(corrected link)*

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all of your code's. check this link and my snippet code: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp#:~:text=The%20box%2Dsizing%20property%20allows,are%20the%20same%20size%20now](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp#:%7E:text=The%20box%2Dsizing%20property%20allows,are%20the%20same%20size%20now)! and let me know if my answer is useful or not.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: url(test4.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font: sans-serif;
}
 
* {
box-sizing: border-box;

}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 10, 0, 0.5);
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 40%;
}
 
.password,
.password-input,
.username,
.username-input {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 90%;
}
 
.btn {
    width: 90%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #35aa23;
    color: white;
}
 
.password,
.username {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font: sans-serif;
}
 
.password-input,
.username-input {
    color: white;
    font: sans-serif;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #35aa23;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 
 
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div class="username-div">
            <span class=" username ">Username</span>
        </div>
 
        <div class="username-input-div">
            <input type="text " class="username-input " name=" " id=" ">
        </div>
 
        <div class="password-div">
            <span class="password ">Password</span>
        </div>
 
        <div class="passoword-input-div">
            <input type="password" class="password-input ">
        </div>
 
        <div class="btn-div">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sig in">
        </div>
 
 
    </div>
 
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you add `text-align: center` to your h1 element.

[image]

Comment: his quote: "I want to centralize that "Login" text in the center, i know i can use `text-align:center;`. My question is: When I try to use padding-left or margin-left, the text just doesn't move to the right."

Comment: Aha, you're right then the whole problem didn't make sense. Bad description of the desired outcome.